# Creating A New List Using List Picker

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic

I'm attempting to create a new list using ListPicker[] to select elements from a list instead of:

```
list={"English", "Japanese", "Spanish", "French"};
newList=list[[{1,4}]]
```

Instead, I'm trying to do this in an interactive manner.

```
ListPicker[{"English"}, {"English", "Japanese", "Spanish", "French"}]
```

[image]

From this list, is it possible to select certain elements to generate a new list?

For example, if I selected English & Spanish, a new list would be made such that:

```
{"English","Spanish"}
```

Comment: `ListPicker[Dynamic[selection], list]` then `Dynamic[selection]` will contain the current value

Comment: ^ this is in the documentation, however I suspect you want to make a new ListPicker based on the previous multi-selection (?) If so, you will need a button that confirms the selection so you can generate the next picker, because Dynamic[selection] updates immediately on the change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = {"English"};
ListPicker[Dynamic[x], {"English", "Japanese", "Spanish", "French"}]

Dynamic[x]
```

The output will be:

[image]

[image]

If you then e.g. click "Ctrl "Spanish"", you get:

[image]

[image]